# Max retries exceeded with url. Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I would like to send a post request to a specific API. Everything went fine when I ran those codes by the local terminal. But when I moved them to an online-based platform, for example Google Colab Notebook, online Python kernels..., a popular error has been returned.
I tried many suggested solutions from several similar questions but no one worked for me.

This is the python codes lines for the post requests.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.customs.gov.vn/bridge?url=/customs/api/GetTKHQInfo'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
response = requests.post(url, json={"skip":0,"take":20,"ky":"","textSearch":"","the_loai":"0","thoigianCongBo":"","typeName":"GetListSoLieu"})
print(response.json())
```

And the following error has been returned when I ran them by the online-based platform, for example Google Colab Notebook:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.customs.gov.vn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bridge?url=/customs/api/GetTKHQInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7f6648a6d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

I am new to scraping data and looking forward to your reply.